# Geoserver Wfs-t always return <ogc:FeatureId fid="none" />

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I have one problem when i need get the response from wfs-t . 
In my request have ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:BLAC="blac.pbh.gov.br"         
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="blac.pbh.gov.br https://xx.xx.xxx.xx/blac/wfs?request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;TYPENAME=blac:EDIF_CROQUI_IMOVEL_IPTU" version="1.0.0" service="WFS" lockAction="ALL"><Update typeName="blac:EDIF_CROQUI_IMOVEL_IPTU"><Property><Name>COD_EDIFICACAO</Name>
<Value>03</Value>
</Property>
<Property><Name>ID_TIPO_CONSTRUTIVO</Name>
<Value>3</Value>
</Property>
<Property><Name>ID_CROQUI_IMOVEL_IPTU</Name>
<Value>49661</Value>
</Property>
<Property><Name>NUM_PAVIMENTO</Name>
<Value>1</Value>
</Property>
<ogc:Filter><ogc:Filter><ogc:FeatureId fid="EDIF_CROQUI_IMOVEL_IPTU.236511"/>
</ogc:Filter>
</ogc:Filter>
</Update>
</Transaction>
```

This request return sucess, but the tag   always is equal "none".

```
<wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse version="1.0.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs https://blac-
hm.pbh.gov.br:443/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">
<wfs:InsertResult>        <ogc:FeatureId fid="none" />
</wfs:InsertResult>
<wfs:TransactionResult>
    <wfs:Status>            <wfs:SUCCESS />
</wfs:Status>
</wfs:TransactionResult>
</wfs:WFS_TransactionResponse>
```

Why does this value always come as "none", even the update being done correctly in the database?

Comment: What do you use as a datastore? If you use shapefiles they most probably do not work correctly. PostGIS and Oracle should behave right if correctly configured.